# Is there a query in elastic search that will provide the most recent sortkey for a given page if I give it the page number and the size?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a query in elastic search that will provide the most recent sort key for a given page if I give it the page size and the size? Even for the data that was added to the record after 10,000,
As I need this to do a search in a table with more than 10 thousand values.

Comment: Have you ever checked the `sort`  ?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html

Comment: I have, 
My needs, though, are a little different.
I'm looking for a query that will return the sort key so that I won't have to rely on a prior request call to get the sort key in order to do a search_after function call.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html